# File upload input from AJAX retrieved file not being detected

Tags: php, sql, ajax, file-upload

I made a dynamically changing `HTML` form where I can change the type of input of the form between a file upload or a drop down box that is populated from a remote database. The function that calls which input type to be displayed is in `AJAX`. When I submit the form using the drop down box, the form submits without any problems and performs the update to the database that I programmed it to do. However, when I try to submit the form while trying to upload the file, my error checking script (which are simple `if... statements`) tells me that it BOTH doesn't detect any file being uploaded and the file already exists on the database. However, when the "already exists on database" error appears, it doesn't return the name of the file that I'm trying to upload like I programmed it to do, so I suspect that my file isn't being submitted properly.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Here's the script I have so far:

**File 1:** test.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <head>
    <script>
    function getInput(value)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (value=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","grabtest.php?q="+value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
    <?php
    // connect to database on server
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database name");
    // if there was an error in connecting to the database, display the error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>
</head>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test2.php" method="POST">
   <select id='SelectInput' onchange='getInput(this.value)'>
      <option selected value=''>Select</option>
      <option value='N'>New File</option>
      <option value='E'>Existing File</option>
   </select>
<div id="display"></div><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
      $target = 'PathName/TargetFolder/';
      $target = $target . basename($FILES['file']['name']);
      if (file_exists('PathName/TargetFolder/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists on server. ";
      }
      else{
        $upload = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $select = mysqli_query($con, "Select Files from DB_Table where Files = '$upload'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0){
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists in database. ";
        }
        else{
        //script for moving the uploaded file to the proper storage location on the server and adding it to the database
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . $target . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            $insert="INSERT INTO DB_Table (Files) VALUES ('$upload')";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "Your data has been added to the database";
        }
    }
    if ($_POST['recipe']=="" and !file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) and !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
      exit("Please select or add the file.");
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**File 2:** *grabtest.php*

```
<?php
//connect to database on server
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database name");
//if there was an error in connecting to the database, display the error
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$q=$_GET["q"];

if ($q==""){
    echo "";
}

elseif ($q=="N"){
    echo "Select recipe to upload: <input type='file' name='newfile'>";
}

elseif ($q=="E"){
    //creates a dropdown box where you can select desired field
    $list = mysqli_query($con, "select * from DB_Table");
    echo 'Files: <select name = "Files">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list))
    {
        echo '<option value = "' . $row["ID"] . '">' . $row["Files"] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br>';
    echo '</form>';
}



//after script is executed, close connection to database
//this improves security by ensuring the connection to the database does not remain open when there is no activity being done to change the data
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I would consider using jquery for your ajax calls, it makes life a lot easier :)....and PDO for handling the sql in php

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and your upload code allows a malicious user to scribble a file anywhere on your server they want. Your are opening your server up to a **COMPLETE** remote takeover.

Comment: A.O. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually just learning web development for the the first time, so I'm completely unfamiliar with jquery. The only thing I know about it is its name. Could you possibly give me a relative example of what jquery would look like?

Comment: Marc B, Thanks for the feedback. Like I said, I'm a novice web developer. I've actually been practicing scripts like these for barely over a month. The server I am operating on is, in fact, used by me alone, and does not have any highly sensitive information. I understand and appreciate your concern, but at this point, an attack would not spell disaster by any means, so I would like to simply try to get the script to do what I ask it to. Do you have suggestions for making my script work?

Comment: It will take some reading and practice but if you're just starting out I would def recommend using jQuery, it especially simplifies ajax calls. Here is a link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ that shows examples, there is a lot of info there the more common attributes are url (location of php file), dataType (type of data to be returned), data (data to be sent with call), success (callback that returns data from server), complete (final callback after everything else has finished.

Comment: A.O. Thank you very much for the help! The link has a lot of information.